# Rails 3.1 and MongoDB - ActiveRecords?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, scaffolding

I try to use first time MongoDB instead of MySQL in my Rails 3.1 app and I am a bit confuse about the rules around.

I know MongoDB is NoSQL and document database and stuffs like that. But what I would like to ask, is - I am accustomed from a work with MySQL with an associations between tables and scaffold generating and migrations.

Is it possible to use here with a work in MongoDB? I try to find a good tutorial for this on Google, but I still can't find the good source about it...

Have anyone any good a tip around this things?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveRecord won't work with MongoDB. You need another library.

I recommend [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org). It's good, documentation is excellent. Check it out.
It installs its own generators, so you can scaffold away.
Oh, and you don't need migrations with MongoDB.

I also heard good things about [MongoMapper](http://mongomapper.com).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I use Mongoid and it's really great.

It's very similar to ActiveRecord, and you can easily do the same things. There are also scaffolding for mongoid, for instance:

```
rails g scaffold article name:string content:text
```

will generate the article model and all the linked scaffold